# Angular 2 Cannot match Route error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am getting angular route error

Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError

Below is my route object:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: TrendsComponent},
  { path: 'trends', component: TrendsComponent }
];
```

I am using @angular/router 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up your routes in the follow way, utilizing a `redirectTo` to route the user to path "/trends" on startup.

Make sure you are importing RouterModule into your `NgModule`. For the root module or similar you'd use `RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)` and for feature modules you'd use `RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)`. Be sure to include `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in both the root and in any feature modules.

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'trends', component: TrendsComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/trends', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
      <p>Redirect to path /trends component is occurring on startup</p>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES) ],
  declarations: [ App, TrendsComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tLxku163CAQwuvvSemuT?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality.

**Updated:** [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/toKiCfTzDLP7hOAwqdW0?p=preview) has been updated to show declaring and importing child routes and modules (non lazy loading).

Hopefully that helps.